# I installed IQKeyboardManager to my project in Xcode to fix my keyboard moving my text field out of the way, however, the pod has no effect on my app

Tags: swift, xcode, iqkeyboardmanager

I installed IQKeyboardManager pod to my project. I followed the YouTube video recommended by the Git page. I also followed the steps that the Git repository recommeded. I added the code that was needed to make the library work, but it still does not work. I am sure this is a simple fix. But I just can't get it working. I also imported the proper library too.

There are two text fields above the two buttons at the top of the screen. I was expecting the keyboard to slide up but keep the text field in view so you can see what you are typing.

The code I entered was according to the git repository:

```
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift

   class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

        var window: UIWindow?

        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

          IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true

          return true
        }
    }
    }
```